# How do I make a bot that joins a voice channel when a specific person joins a voice channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Very new to this. I've been reading the readthedocs API reference for discord.py and it's isn't making a lot of sense to me. So far I have

```
import os
import discord
#os.environ['targetID']

bot = discord.Client()
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True


channel_id = os.environ['channelID']
voice_channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)

async def on_ready():
  print ("Ready")
  channel_id = os.environ['channelID']
  voice_channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
  await voice_channel.connect()


#async def on_voice_state_update(Member, channel[None], channel['general']):
#  print(client.member.id)

#move_to(None)
bot.run(os.environ['token'])
```

The goal is to get the bot to join the voice channel that the user with the `targetID` join, but I'm having trouble just getting the bot to join a channel in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of **Nathan Marotte** I will provide a code example.

You can use an [on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.on_voice_state_update) function in order to check in which channel the member is.

Therefore take a look at the following **code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    targetID = bot.get_user(TargetIDHere)

    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None and member.id == targetID.id: # Condition that must be fulfilled
        await member.voice.channel.connect() # Connect to the channel
```

***To explain the different functions in the code:***

`before.channel is None` = Checks that the user is not in a channel/was not in a channel.

`after.channel is not None` = Checks the channel which the user joined and then grants the role.

`member.id == targetID.id` = Checks if the `member.id` that joined matches `targetID.id`.

Answer (score 0):

[on_voice_state_update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.on_voice_state_update) is what you need. This event will be called when a change of voice state happens on the server, this includes

- A member joins a voice channel.
- A member leaves a voice channel.
- A member is muted or deafened by their own accord.
- A member is muted or deafened by a guild administrator.

This function takes 3 parameters, the member to which the update occurred, the state before, and the state after.
When this event is triggered, check that `member.id == target_member.id`. If it is the case, then `await after.channel.connect()`

You should also add checking if the bot is not already in this channel and other stuff but this should point you in the right direction